Error in Odoo 8 module: Missing Error what is the solution?
Good afternoon, I have an error in my Odoo 8 module, the error is like this: MissingError
One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing.
Screenshoot Error: Screenshoot Error 1 Screenshoot Error 2
Detail full error:
File "C:\Tunas_Ridean\Odoo-8.0\addons\sale\sale.py", line 1067, in product_id_change
    if product_obj.taxes_id:
  File "C:\Tunas_Ridean\Odoo-8.0\openerp\fields.py", line 840, in __get__
    return record._cache[self]
  File "C:\Tunas_Ridean\Odoo-8.0\openerp\models.py", line 6041, in __getitem__
    return value.get() if isinstance(value, SpecialValue) else value
  File "C:\Tunas_Ridean\Odoo-8.0\openerp\fields.py", line 56, in get
    raise self.exception
MissingError: ('MissingError', u'One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing.')

My Code Modul:
File Script Models sale_order.py:
# models/sale_order.py
from openerp import models, fields
from openerp import api

class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    product_id = fields.Many2one(
        'product.custom', string='Product', required=True,
        domain=[('state', 'in', ['confirmed', 'approved'])]
    )

    price_unit = fields.Float(
        string='Price Unit',
        related='product_id.price',  # Mengambil harga dari `product.custom`
        store=True,
        readonly=True
    )
    
    @api.onchange('product_id.price','price_unit')
    def _onchange_product_id(self):
        #import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        self.price_unit = self.product_id.price
        self.name = self.product_id.description
        self.product_uom_qty = self.product_id.qty

File Script XML sale_order_view.xml:
<!-- views/sale_order_view.xml -->
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="view_order_form_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='product_id']" position="replace">
                <field name="product_id"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='price_unit']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
    </data>
</openerp>


You have changed the relation in the Many2one field product_id to a different model. But product_id is used in a lot of business logic. Part of this business logic probably calls subfields that your model simply does not have. This is just a guess, but it should be very close to a correct answer.
My advice: I would not radically change such a core component as products in order lines as you are doing. Better try another way, e.g. a new field custom_product_id or something similar.

How to solve? Iam don't understand you mean

I wrote an advice... there are several ways to fix. Just two: let your changes stay and try to fix every business logic where product_id is involved (could take you days to weeks of work) OR take my advice into consideration and don't change product_id at all.

Okay, thanks for solution.
